# performance issue: inner join across multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to speed up this query but can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

I'm on Postgres 11.8.

observations has ~250M rows
report_items has ~35M rows
report_sections has ~3M rows

Query

```
SELECT "observations".* FROM "observations" 
INNER JOIN "report_items" ON "observations"."report_item_id" = "report_items"."id" 
INNER JOIN "report_sections" ON "report_items"."report_section_id" = "report_sections"."id" 
WHERE 
    "observations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
    "report_items"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
    "report_sections"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
    "report_sections"."report_id" = '87996789-795f-402c-af8c-181d27eb6dc0';
```

Explain Plan

```
Gather  (cost=1000.23..1261158.89 rows=3691 width=539) (actual time=921.292..988.896 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 3
  Workers Launched: 3
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.23..1259789.79 rows=1191 width=539) (actual time=916.410..916.410 rows=0 loops=4)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.11..715317.61 rows=176 width=16) (actual time=916.409..916.409 rows=0 loops=4)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on report_sections  (cost=0.00..710432.51 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=916.409..916.409 rows=0 loops=4)
                    Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (report_id = '87996789-795f-402c-af8c-181d27eb6dc0'::uuid))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 693631
              ->  Index Scan using index_report_items_on_deleted_at_and_report_section_id on report_items  (cost=0.11..243.89 rows=121 width=32) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (report_section_id = report_sections.id))
        ->  Index Scan using index_observations_where_deleted_at_null_on_report_item_id on observations  (cost=0.11..3086.96 rows=2211 width=539) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (report_item_id = report_items.id)
Planning Time: 0.497 ms
Execution Time: 988.949 ms
```

Thank for the help in advance!

EDITED:

Here are the indexes on the `report_sections` table: https://share.getcloudapp.com/xQuDqj0K

Comment: Are there many rows in `report_sections` where `deleted_at` is NULL?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, about 92% of the 2.8M rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This index would speed up processing:

```
CREATE INDEX ON report_sections (report_id) INCLUDE (id)
   WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Then `VACUUM` the table and try again; you should get a fast index only scan.

Answer (score 1):

The sequential scan of `report_sections` is taking the bulk of the time.

Is there a reason why `report_sections.report_id` is not indexed?

Comment: Thanks, Mike! I am seeing that I have an index on `report_sections.report_id`. Here are the indexes in place: https://share.getcloudapp.com/xQuDqj0K

Comment: @jdixon04  I apologize for assuming that it was not indexed.  The question is why it opts for a seq scan.  Have you tried to `analyze` the table?